# Will the second column on ORDER BY be checked if the first one is unique?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a query like this:

```
. . . ORDER BY col1, MAX(col2)
```

`col1` is unique in the most of times, and usually `col1` is different between selected rows. All I want to know, when `col1` is different, then will `MAX(col2)` be executed? Because executing of that would be useless.

let me ask my question the other way:

```
. . . ORDER BY id, name
```

As you know `id` is unique. In this case will `name` even be checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much more complicated.

I understand your point and yes, it is needless to check for second column, if the first one is already unique, but from other view:

**Why you include the second column, if the first one is already unique?**

Anyway, this logic works, if we imagine sorting as simple iteration process, but as it is described in [ORDER BY Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) it is not so.

**Sample 1** - `. . . ORDER BY col1, MAX(col2)`

For that case you have used `GROUP BY` somewhere in your SQL and optimization guide suggests following:

> By default, MySQL sorts all GROUP BY col1, col2, ... queries as if you
>   specified ORDER BY col1, col2, ... in the query as well. If you
>   include an explicit ORDER BY clause that contains the same column
>   list, MySQL optimizes it away without any speed penalty, although the
>   sorting still occurs.

**Sample 2** - `. . . ORDER BY id, name`

As the guide suggests, it all depends on the indexes that you have defined:

> In some cases, MySQL can use an index to satisfy an ORDER BY clause
>   without doing extra sorting.
>   The index can also be used even if the ORDER BY does not match the
>   index exactly, as long as all unused portions of the index and all
>   extra ORDER BY columns are constants in the WHERE clause.

To make sure how your query works, just use `EXPLAIN SELECT ... ORDER BY` to see how it is being processed.